What is the difference between band gap and band edge in QDs or semiconductors?
I am studying AgInS2 quantum dots which are semiconductor nanoparticles. I obtain the absorbance spectrum using the spectrophotometer. in the spectrum, I observe a shoulder-like feature. It is common in other QDs too, such as CuInS2 QDs. Researchers have interpreted it as the band-edge. In QDs such as CdSe or PbS, the absorbance spectrum has an absorbance peak, and it is interpreted as the band gap in the research papers. In the literature available for AgInS2 QDs, the band gap is found using the Tauc plot.
My AgInS2 QDs have a shoulder-like feature in the absorbance spectrum. I want to know how to interpret that feature. whether it's the band edge or the band gap?
I also want to know why was Tauc plot not used in PbS QDs to determine the band gap?

Direct vs indirect bandgap, crystalline vs amorphous, high vs low doping, variations on what is considered a Tauc plot vs other, similar, representations of absorption vs energy, ... For a good introductory text I'd suggest Jacques Pankove, Optical Processes in Semiconductors (Dover, so inexpensive too).
